# Fill an Outlook mail with date

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to fill automatically an Outlook mail with date.

Output should be something like:

> Hi,
> I send you report related to week [Today - 5days] - [Today]
> Kind regards

I use this macro in Word. How do I do the same in Outlook?

```vb
Sub InsertFirstAndLastDayOfWeek()
    Dim firstDay As Date
    Dim lastDay As Date
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim additionalText As String
    additionalText = "Hi" & vbCrLf
    currentDate = Date
    firstDay = currentDate - (Weekday(currentDate, vbMonday) - 1)
    lastDay = firstDay + 4
    objMail.Body= Selection.TypeText additionalText
    Selection.TypeText "Report from " & Format(firstDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ", "
    Selection.TypeText "to " & Format(lastDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "."
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post the code you tried, along with a specific description of what problems you had with it, so people can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but you need to initialize objMail to get this code work.

Try sample,

```
Sub InsertFirstAndLastDayOfWeek()
Dim firstDay As Date
Dim lastDay As Date
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim additionalText As String
Dim content As String
additionalText = "Hi" & vbCrLf
currentDate = Date
firstDay = currentDate - (Weekday(currentDate, vbMonday) - 1)
lastDay = firstDay + 4

Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then Set objMail = insp.CurrentItem
content = "Report from " & Format(firstDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ", to " & Format(lastDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "."
objMail.Body = additionalText & vbNewLine & content & vbNewLine & objMail.Body
End Sub
```